# AD group name with '/' character is blowing up my binding

Tags: .net, directoryservices

I get the memberOf property for my user using this code:

```
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry(connectionString));
search.Filter=string.Format("(&(sAMAccountName={0})(objectClass=user))",userName);
SearchResult result = search.FirndOne();
```

So far so good.
However I then have to get the cn value for each group the user is a member of:  I do that in a loop over the memberOf property.

```
List<string> groupList = new List<string>();
DirectoryEntry user = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

foreach(string groupPath in user.Properties["memberOf"])
{
    DirectoryEntry groupBinding = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://"+groupPath);
    DirectorySearcher groupSearch = new DirectorySearcher(groupBinding);
    DirectoryEntry gorupEntry = groupSearch.FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry();
    groupList.Add(groupEntry.Properties["cn"].Value.ToString()));
}
```

The issue is that when the groupPath includes a '/' character the `groupSearch.FindOne()` throws an exception.

How do I escape the / character so that I can search for that group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the backslash to escape so /

Credit: http://www.rlmueller.net/CharactersEscaped.htm